# Rails association conundrum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'm creating a service to store food recipes, and I'm trying to create a list of ingredients with optional preferred brands for each ingredient.  So, for example, I might say that a pasta recipe uses peeled tomatoes and the preferred brand is Cento.  My ingredients are stored in a hierarchical category tree, so the preferred ingredient is a child of the ingredient in that tree.

Here's my simplified database setup:

```
recipes
- name
- instructions

ingredients
- name

recipe_ingredients
- recipe_id
- ingredient_id
- preferred_ingredient_id
- amount
```

And the associations:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :ingredients, :through => :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :preferred_ingredients, :through => :recipe_ingredients
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class RecipeIngredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  has_one :ingredient
  has_one :preferred_ingredient
end
```

I'm not sure how to handle that preferred_ingredient_id and ingredient_id both point to the same model and that :preferred_ingredients doesn't actually exist as a symbol.  Do I need to set up my associations differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're storing the ingredient reference in RecipeIngredient,

```
belongs_to :preferred_ingredient, class_name: 'Ingredient'
```

I'd also think you're referencing the ingredients in RecipeIngredient, so you'd want to change the `has_one` to `belongs_to` there as well.  (Would it make sense that the ingredient is destroyed if the recipe is deleted?)

But considering that you may actually have many options for a particular ingredient, you might be looking for something more like this:

RecipeIngredient:

```
belongs_to :recipe
belongs_to :preferred_ingredient, class_name: 'Ingredient'
has_many :ingredient_options
has_many :ingredients, through: :ingredient_options
```

IngredientOption

```
belongs_to :recipe_ingredient
belongs_to :ingredient
```

Comment: `model_name` is an Unknown key for belongs_to association 
`belongs_to :preferred_ingredient, class_name: 'Ingredient'`
it should be instead

Answer (score 0):

You may also have a look @ [self-referential-association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association)

and also this might help you
[Rails Associations - has_many => :through - but same model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559164/rails-associations-has-many-through-but-same-model)